# Pre-boot error message: DIMM configuration error

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

Whenever I start my PC I get the following error message

```
DUAL CHANNEL OPERATION REQUIRES IDENTICAL PAIRED DIMMA INSTALLED ACROSS BOTH MEMORY CHANNELS
BIOS HAS DETECTED A NON OPTIMAL MEMORY CONFIGURATION CAN IMPROVE THE SYSTEM'S MEMORY BUS BANDWIDTH
CHANNEL A, DIMM 0 SHOULD MATCH CHANNEL B, DIMM 0
CHANNEL A, DIMM 1 SHOULD MATCH CHANNEL B, DIMM 1
CMOS/GPNV CHECKSUM BAD
PRESS F4 TO RUN SETUP
```

I have two slots for RAM, one has a 512 MB and the other a 1 GB chip.
My system used to work fine but recently I have this error message regularly coming up.
I press `F4` from the BIOS I set the correct time and then my computer boots normally, and works fine, but when I boot it the next time the same things happen again.

Comment: Personally, I'd be more concerned with the `CMOS/GPNV CHECKSUM BAD` part... Are you sure the motherboard only has two DIMM slots?  The above output indicates it has two DIMMs per channel, and there are two channels.  Anyways, does this also mean that your computer is working fine (aside from this error message)?

Comment: Yes my computer is working fine. As for the slots I am not very sure but I found only two of them when I opened the cpu cabinet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set the correct time (and date?) every time you boot up your computer, that is a strong hint, that the CMOS battery needs replacement. And that's why there's also a CMOS checksum error, too. Usually it's a flat lithium button cell (20mm diameter), labelled CR2032 or CR2025.

[image]

Comment: does that DIMM error is due to the cmos battery ?

Comment: @AniketAman: As you say your computer is running fine, I suppose yes.